# Prettier to format .vue

Tags: vue.js, visual-studio-code, eslint, prettier

Prettier VS Code extension doesn't work properly with .vue. I mean how to setup prettier to integrate it with eslint and format .vue files on `Cmd+Shift+P -> Format Document`. `.eslintrc.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  root: true,
  env: {
    browser: true,
  },
  extends: [
    'plugin:vue/essential',
    'standard'
  ],
  plugins: [
    'vue'
  ]
}
```

Comment: Maye this is of help: https://github.com/prettier/prettier-vscode/issues/590#issuecomment-428654972

Comment: @SølveTornøe it didn't. Strange thing that prettier format .js fine (as it supposed in standard style), but in .vue it formats another way (with semicolon, double qoutes etc)

Answer (score 7):

Easier is to install vetur `octref.vetur` extension and then add a .vscode>settings.json with following

```
{
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "octref.vetur",
    "vetur.format.defaultFormatter.html": "prettier",
    "vetur.format.defaultFormatter.css": "prettier",
    "vetur.format.defaultFormatter.postcss": "prettier",
    "vetur.format.defaultFormatter.scss": "prettier",
    "vetur.format.defaultFormatter.less": "prettier",
    "vetur.format.defaultFormatter.stylus": "stylus-supremacy",
    "vetur.format.defaultFormatter.js": "prettier",
    "vetur.format.defaultFormatter.ts": "prettier"
}
```

[image]

Comment: how can i setup rule option for html code in prettier.config.js?

Answer (score 6):

You need to define those rules in your `.eslintrc.js` file like this:

```
module.exports = {
  root: true,
  env: {
    node: true
  },
  extends: ["plugin:vue/essential", "@vue/prettier"],
  rules: {
    "no-console": process.env.NODE_ENV === "production" ? "error" : "off",
    "no-debugger": process.env.NODE_ENV === "production" ? "error" : "off",
    "prettier/prettier": [
      "warn",
      {
        "singleQuote": true,
        "semi": false,
        "trailingComma": "none"
      }
    ]
  },
  parserOptions: {
    parser: "babel-eslint"
  }
};
```

Answer (score -1):

you can add .prettierrc.json file in the root directory, and

```
{
  "singleQuote": true,
  "tabWidth": 2,
  "semi": false
}
```

Answer (score -1):

./.prettierr.js (file in root folder, that is)

```js
module.exports = {
    //your rules here
    trailingComma: 'none',
    tabWidth: 2,
    singleQuote: true,
    semi: false
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).